# How to redirect all pages except Home page to login/register

Tags: wordpress, authentication, redirect

On a wordpress site, I want to redirect all not logged in users to the login/register page except the home page, so any other page on the site needs to check the logged in status.

I am trying this;
add_action( 'template_redirect', function() {

```
if( ( !is_page('login' || 'home') ) ) {

    if (!is_user_logged_in() ) {
        wp_redirect( site_url( '/login' ) );        // redirect all...
        exit();
    }

}
```

});

But this does not work.

Answer (score 0):

Set login as homepage in the theme customizable.
Then
if !page (home , xhome)

if !userLog redirecting => homepage.

So, basically treat login page as homepage then home as regular page.

Comment: I want the home page visible as well as the login page.